# How to pass AngularJS directives through a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd simply like to know if there's a best practice for using Angular directives (i.e. ngModel, ngClick, ngShow, etc) within a custom directive. So far I've been creating custom attributes then passing that attribute to the template as the value of the directive. Is there a better way to do this? It seems more efficient to call Angular directives directly.

I've seen references to `'&ngClick'` within the isolate scope... What's the use case for this? How does it differ from just using `'&'`?

What I would like to do...

```
<my-directive ng-model="myModel" ng-click="myAction(args)"></my-directive>
```

What I've been doing...

```
<my-directive model="myModel" action="myAction()"></my-directive>

...
  scope: { model: '=', action: '&' },
  template: '<div ng-model="model" ng-click="action">Click me</div>'
```

---

Edit: As requested, I've added some code as an illustration.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xOtaxYM1QsP5LmmWPcoB?p=preview

This doesn't work. It doesn't compile (or link?) properly. So what's missing to pass Angular directives through this?

Comment: directives are very powerful. Hard to make generalizations sometimes without seeing more of the useage. Suggest you create a semi real world demo in plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: regarding `&ngClick` - that's the same as using `&` but allows you to specify a name other than `ngClick` for the property within the isolate scope. I.e. You could use `scope: { clickAction: '&ngClick' }`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at the AngularJS documentation page. There is an in-depth explanation of what directive is and can do along with **best practices**. It is worth taking a look at it.

[AngularJS directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

The second part of your example (`template: '<div ng-model="model" ng-click="action">Click me</div>'`) embeds commands (i.e. `ng-click`). In that case your template should be compiled using `$compile`.

Interestingly the documentation states: "**Best Practice: It's recommended to use the directive definition object form.**".

To me it means you should go for the regular way of using directive; `$compile` comes second. It means you should go for `<my-directive ng-model="myModel" ng-click="myAction(args)"></my-directive>` instead of `template: '<div ng-model="model" ng-click="action">Click me</div>'`.

Well it may not always be possible; as said above you should provide us with a concrete use case if you want a fine-tuned answer.

[AngularJS $compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

Comment: Been a while since I'd looked over the official docs but it's been helpful. (I spend more time in the API docs.) Starting to make more sense now the more I learn about Angular. I was intentionally trying to keep things generalized. Maybe too much I guess. I've added some broken code as an example.